# Make a JAR lib from an Android library module

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-studio, aar

From Android Studio, I have made a new Android Module (apply plugin: 'com.android.library') which contains some java classes,  a res folder (with some resources), and an AndroidManifest.xml file which holds some exported elements, such as a BroadcastReceiver, which I would like the projects to have merged inside their AndroidManifest. This library module works great when I export it as an AAR, or publish it to a maven repo, and other applications can use it properly any way they like.

I would like this library to be available for android applications which use Eclipse as their dev environment, and there still seems to be some people which still use Eclipse (probably for historical reasons). So, my question is: do Eclipse android applications have a way to import AAR libs? If not, should I consider making a JAR lib? Inside this JAR lib, should I include resources? What about the manifest file? If I don't include it inside the JAR, should I guide users to modify their manifest when using this JAR?

Thanks for any help.